# How to use "sometimes()" - Laravel validation, method in foreach construction

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel, and I have the next problem - I get a `null` value of variable in `$validator` object:

```
class PageRequest extends Request
{
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();
        foreach (\Config::get('app.all_langs') as $locale) {
            dump($locale); // !!!!! all it's ok - en, ro, ru
            $validator->sometimes('alias'.$locale,'unique:pages,alias->'.$locale.'|max:255', function($input) {
                dump($locale]); // ????? - null instead of en, ro, ru
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `use` construct in order to access variables from the parent scope inside a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), like `function($input) use ($locale)`. For example:

```
$validator->sometimes('alias'.$locale,'unique:pages,alias->'.$locale.'|max:255', function($input) use ($locale) {
   dump($locale); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inherit variables from the parent scope you should use the `use` construct:

Your new code should be like this:

```
class PageRequest extends Request
{
    protected function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();
        foreach (\Config::get('app.all_langs') as $locale) {
            dump($locale); // !!!!! all it's ok - en, ro, ru
            $validator->sometimes('alias'.$locale,'unique:pages,alias->'.$locale.'|max:255', function($input) use ($locale) {
                dd($locale]); // dump it here
            }
    }
}
```